# Negative backlog in Apache Flink Stateful Functions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

How can the backlog of a remote function in Flink Statefun be negative?

On a pipeline I'm currently working on, I see this behaviour regularly when the cluster is under stress and some functions are under backpressure. Then the metrics for the backlog sometimes become negative and stay there. The following chart shows this phenomenon.

[image: Back pressure chart]

According to the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-3.1/docs/deployment/metrics/#metrics) the metric numBacklog is the "The number of pending messages to be sent".

I just don't understand how this can be negative. Does anyone know?

Comment: The number of backlogged messages cannot be negative. It increases if the address is blocked and then immediately resets to zero once it is available. I suspect there is a problem in how the RequestReplyFunction resets the counter metric, but I am unable to reproduce it locally. What version of StateFun are you running? This might be resolved in a more recent release.

Comment: It would also be good to know which metrics reporter you are using.

Comment: Other then the metric appearing to be negative, does overall the application makes progresses? Just trying to understand if it's a reporting issue only.

Comment: Update, I can confirm it is a bug in how the metric is reported. You can assume in this case the actual value is zero. I've opened a ticket to track and fix the problem https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24464

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. I thought I just haven't understood the meaning of the metric. It was with statefun 3.1.0 and using the prometheus metrics.